# Transform:rotate not working on my navbar

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Im trying to make my navbar so that there is an icon for each page, with text rotated 90* next to the icon.  For some reason this isn't working.  Any thoughts?  I know I need the -ms- and -webkit- adjusts, but Im testing this in firefox for now and its not working.

```
<span style="font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, sans-serif;display:inline;float:left;">JOE'S DINER</span>
    <div id="navbar"><span id="icon"> &#xf015 </span><div style="transform:rotate(90deg);display:inline;">Home</div></div> 
    <div id="navbar"><span id="icon"> &#xf083 </span><br/>Menu</div>
    <div id="navbar"><span id="icon"> &#xf091 </span><br/>Pics</div>
    <div id="navbar"><span id="icon"> &#xf007 </span><br/>Foodie Blog</div> 
    <div id="navbar"><span id="icon"> &#xf0e0 </span><br/>Contact Us</div>
```

and heres the css for the ids

```
#navbar{
display:inline;
float:left;
font-size:10px;
text-align:center;
}   

#icon{
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
padding:0 15px;
letter-spacing:12px;
font-size:30px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because your `div` element is set to display `inline` and therefore does not meet the requirements for CSS Transforms [as defined in the W3C Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transformable-element). To paraphrase:

> A transformable element is an element in the HTML namespace which is either:
>
> - [a block-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-level);
> - [an atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13);
> - an element whose `display` property computes to `table-row`, `table-row-group`, `table-header-group`, `table-footer-group`, `table-cell`, or `table-caption`;
> - or an element in the SVG namespace which has the attributes `transform`, `patternTransform` or `gradientTransform`.

Remove the `inline` display declaration from your divider and the transformation will work as specified.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I'll keep that in mind next time!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text in a < p > tag and then:

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/6P6MU/